# How to call a function from an impl in an ident

Tags: rust, macros

How do I call a function from an struct received on a macro?

My actual case is different but I reduced the issue to this piece of code:

```rust
macro_rules! macro_test {
    ($foo:ident) => {
        {
            println!("{}", <$foo>.to_string());
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ss = "sim";
    macro_test!(ss);
}
```

It doesn't compile and I have found no clear answer on how to call `<$received>.function()`.

The error:

```
 Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: expected `::`, found `.`
  --> src/main.rs:4:34
   |
4  |             println!("{}", <$foo>.to_string());
   |                                  ^ expected `::`
...
11 |     macro_test!(ss);
   |     --------------- in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `macro_test` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

[The playgorund to test it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2e91bba36885bb8d46e9dbf01efe23f4) does not compile. I have not found a way to call methods of an ident inside a macro.

Comment: Just remove the `<>` from around `$foo`. I'm surprised you haven't tried that. What led you to put them there in the first place?

Comment: Probably put the <> in there because you need it to call static methods. Welcome to StackOverflow @Cucaracha Anónima